# How to change clarity of an h264 video which decoded by FFMPEG and rendered by opengl

Tags: opengl-es, ffmpeg

I'm writing a movie player that use FFMPEG and OpenGL ES. Movie can be decoded succeessfully, but when I use AVFrame as texture to draw in my screen, I found it was so fuzzy. I don't know where wrong in my code. If I change the AVFrame from YUV to RGB image, it will be clear. 
Does any one know why use YUV as texture to draw will be not clear?

My render code:

```
#import "SJGLView.h"
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>
#import "SJDecoder.h"

#include "libavutil/pixfmt.h"

// MARK: - C Function
static void sj_logShaderError(GLuint shader) {
  GLint info_len = 0;
  glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &info_len);
  if (info_len == 0) NSLog(@"Empty info");
  else {
    GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(info_len);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, info_len, &info_len, log);
    NSLog(@"Shader compile log: %s", log);
  }
}

static void sj_logProgramError(GLuint program) {
  int info_length;
  glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &info_length);
  if (info_length) {
    GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(info_length);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, info_length, &info_length, log);
    NSLog(@"Program link log: %s", log);
  }
}

GLuint sj_loadShader(GLenum shader_type, const char* shader_source) {
  GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shader_type);
  glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shader_source, NULL);
  glCompileShader(shader);
  GLint compile_status = 0;
  glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compile_status);
  if (!compile_status) goto fail;
  return shader;

fail:
  if (shader) {
    sj_logShaderError(shader);
    glDeleteShader(shader);
  }
  return 0;
}

void loadOrtho(float *matrix, float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far) {
  float r_l = right - left;
  float t_b = top - bottom;
  float f_n = far - near;
  float tx = (right + left)/(right - left);
  float ty = (top + bottom)/(top - bottom);
  float tz = (far + near)/(far - near);

  matrix[0] = 2.0f / r_l;
  matrix[1] = 0.0f;
  matrix[2] = 0.0f;
  matrix[3] = 0.0f;

  matrix[4] = 0.0f;
  matrix[5] = 2.0f / t_b;
  matrix[6] = 0.0f;
  matrix[7] = 0.0f;

  matrix[8] = 0.0f;
  matrix[9] = 0.0f;
  matrix[10] = -2.0f / f_n;
  matrix[11] = 0.0f;

  matrix[12] = tx;
  matrix[13] = ty;
  matrix[14] = tz;
  matrix[15] = 1.0f;
}


// BT.709, standard for HDTV
static const GLfloat g_bt709[] = {
  1.164,  1.164,  1.164,
  0.0,   -0.213,  2.112,
  1.793, -0.533,  0.0,
};

const GLfloat *getColorMatrix_bt709() {
  return g_bt709;
}

enum {
  ATTRIBUTE_VERTEX,
  ATTRIBUTE_TEXCOORD,
};

@implementation SJGLView {
  EAGLContext *_context;

  GLuint      _framebuffer;
  GLuint      _renderbuffer;
  GLint       _backingWidth;
  GLint       _backingHeight;
  GLfloat     _vertices[8];
  GLuint      _program;
  GLuint      _av4Position;
  GLuint      _av2Texcoord;
  GLuint      _um4Mvp;
  GLfloat     _texcoords[8];
  GLuint      _us2Sampler[3];
  GLuint      _um3ColorConversion;
  GLuint      _textures[3];

  SJDecoder *_decoder;
}

+ (Class)layerClass {
  return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame decoder:(SJDecoder *)decoder {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    _decoder = decoder;
    [self setupGL];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderbuffer);
  [_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
  glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &_backingWidth);
  glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &_backingHeight);

  [self updateVertices];
  [self render: nil];
}

- (void)setContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode
{
  [super setContentMode:contentMode];
  [self updateVertices];

  [self render:nil];
}


- (void)setupGL {
  _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
  NSAssert(_context != nil, @"Failed to init EAGLContext");

  CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer= (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
  eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
  eaglLayer.drawableProperties = @{
                                   kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                   kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   };

  [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
  if ([self setupEAGLContext]) {
    NSLog(@"Success to setup EAGLContext");
    if ([self loadShaders]) {
      NSLog(@"Success to load shader");
      _us2Sampler[0] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "us2_SamplerX");
      _us2Sampler[1] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "us2_SamplerY");
      _us2Sampler[2] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "us2_SamplerZ");
      _um3ColorConversion = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "um3_ColorConversion");
    }
  }
}

- (BOOL)setupEAGLContext {
  glGenFramebuffers(1, &_framebuffer);
  glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_renderbuffer);
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebuffer);
  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderbuffer);
  [_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];
  glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &_backingWidth);
  glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &_backingHeight);
  glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderbuffer);

  GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
  if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object: %x", status);
    return NO;
  }

  GLenum glError = glGetError();
  if (glError != GL_NO_ERROR) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to setup EAGLContext: %x", glError);
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)loadShaders {
  NSString *vertexPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vertex" ofType:@"vsh"];
  const char *vertexString = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:vertexPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] UTF8String];

  NSString *fragmentPath = _decoder.format == SJVideoFrameFormatYUV ? [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yuv420p" ofType:@"fsh"] :
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rgb" ofType:@"fsh"];
  const char *fragmentString = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fragmentPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] UTF8String];

  GLuint vertexShader = sj_loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexString);
  GLuint fragmentShader = sj_loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentString);

  _program = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(_program, vertexShader);
  glAttachShader(_program, fragmentShader);
  glLinkProgram(_program);
  GLint link_status = GL_FALSE;
  glGetProgramiv(_program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &link_status);
  if(!link_status) goto fail;

  _av4Position = glGetAttribLocation(_program, "av4_Position");
  _av2Texcoord = glGetAttribLocation(_program, "av2_Texcoord");
  _um4Mvp = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "um4_ModelViewProjection");
  return YES;
fail:
  sj_logProgramError(_program);
  glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
  glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
  glDeleteProgram(_program);
  return NO;
}

- (void)useRenderer {
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
  glUseProgram(_program);

  if (0 == _textures[0]) glGenTextures(3, _textures);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[i]);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glUniform1i(_us2Sampler[i], i);
  }
  glUniformMatrix3fv(_um3ColorConversion, 1, GL_FALSE, getColorMatrix_bt709());
}

- (void)uploadTexture:(SJVideoFrame *)frame {
  if (frame.format == SJVideoFrameFormatYUV) {
    SJVideoYUVFrame *yuvFrame = (SJVideoYUVFrame *)frame;
    const GLubyte *pixel[3] = { yuvFrame.luma.bytes, yuvFrame.chromaB.bytes, yuvFrame.chromaR.bytes };
    const GLsizei widths[3] = { yuvFrame.width, yuvFrame.width/2, yuvFrame.width/2 };
    const GLsizei heights[3] = { yuvFrame.height, yuvFrame.height/2, yuvFrame.height/2 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[i]);
      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, widths[i], heights[i], 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel[i]);
    }
  }

}

- (void)render:(SJVideoFrame *)frame {
  [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
  glUseProgram(_program);
  [self useRenderer];
  GLfloat modelviewProj[16];
  loadOrtho(modelviewProj, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(_um4Mvp, 1, GL_FALSE, modelviewProj);
  [self updateVertices];
  [self updateTexcoords];

  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _framebuffer);
  glViewport(0, 0, _backingWidth, _backingHeight);

  [self uploadTexture:frame];
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

  glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _renderbuffer);
  [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}

- (void)updateVertices {
  [self resetVertices];

  BOOL fit        = (self.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit);
  float width     = _decoder.frameWidth;
  float height    = _decoder.frameHeight;
  const float dW  = (float)_backingWidth / width;
  const float dH  = (float)_backingHeight / height;
  float dd        = fit ? MIN(dH, dW) : MAX(dH, dW);
  float nW        = (width  * dd / (float)_backingWidth);
  float nH        = (height * dd / (float)_backingHeight);

  _vertices[0] = -nW;
  _vertices[1] = -nH;
  _vertices[2] =  nW;
  _vertices[3] = -nH;
  _vertices[4] = -nW;
  _vertices[5] =  nH;
  _vertices[6] =  nW;
  _vertices[7] =  nH;

  glVertexAttribPointer(_av4Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _vertices);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(_av4Position);
}

- (void)resetVertices {
  _vertices[0] = -1.0f;
  _vertices[1] = -1.0f;
  _vertices[2] =  1.0f;
  _vertices[3] = -1.0f;
  _vertices[4] = -1.0f;
  _vertices[5] =  1.0f;
  _vertices[6] =  1.0f;
  _vertices[7] =  1.0f;
}

- (void)updateTexcoords {
  [self resetTexcoords];

  glVertexAttribPointer(_av2Texcoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _texcoords);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(_av2Texcoord);
}

- (void)resetTexcoords {
  _texcoords[0] = 0.0f;
  _texcoords[1] = 1.0f;
  _texcoords[2] = 1.0f;
  _texcoords[3] = 1.0f;
  _texcoords[4] = 0.0f;
  _texcoords[5] = 0.0f;
  _texcoords[6] = 1.0f;
  _texcoords[7] = 0.0f;
}
```

.fsh :

```
precision highp float;
varying   highp vec2 vv2_Texcoord;
uniform   mat3  um3_ColorConversion;
uniform   lowp  sampler2D us2_SamplerX;
uniform   lowp  sampler2D us2_SamplerY;
uniform   lowp  sampler2D us2_SamplerZ;
void main() {
  mediump vec3 yuv;
  lowp    vec3 rgb;
  yuv.x = (texture2D(us2_SamplerX, vv2_Texcoord).r - (16.0/255.0));
  yuv.y = (texture2D(us2_SamplerY, vv2_Texcoord).r - 0.5);
  yuv.z = (texture2D(us2_SamplerZ, vv2_Texcoord).r - 0.5);
  rgb = um3_ColorConversion * yuva;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
}
```

.vsh file:

```
precision highp float;
varying highp vec2 vv2_Texcoord;
uniform lowp sampler2D us2_SamplerX;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(us2_SamplerX, vv2_Texcoord).rgb, 1)
}
```

The rgb image:
[RGB image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1uQQ.jpg)

---

Update to add a GL_NEAREST image:

[GL_NEAREST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YvfW.png)

Comment: So if you draw using the same drawing code in opengl, but just feeding RGB and skip the color conversion, then it's sharp ?

Comment: It's not clear too.

Comment: Ok, so the problem has nothing to do with YUV, it's just when you draw your video with OpenGL, things are blurry. My guess is that it's just the effect of OpenGL bilinear filtering which isn't exactly the best resize filter. What's the video resolution compared to the surface you display ?

Comment: My code is base on kxmovie, and I found that some people has same question with me. While playing h264 video, the view is fuzzy. But I can't find resolution. The video solution is 1920*960.

Comment: can you try with GL_NEAREST instead of GL_LINEAR and post a screenshot to confirm the filtering is the issue ?

Comment: I have post  a screenshot . It loos like have no change with the original one.

Comment: I have solved this question. Before opengl  draw yuv frame, should set contentscale of eagllayer...